# GLSL for sprite sheet

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a shader that renders a simple texture on the screen. But, consider that I have a sprite sheet (multiple frames for a sprite) and I want to render just a small portion of that sheet (a frame), how would I do that using GLSL?

I do not want to manipulate the vertex buffer since that would become extremely costly.

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 position, vec2 texCoords>

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
    gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec4 color;

void main()
{    
    FragColor = texture(texture, TexCoords) * color;
}
```

Here is how I calculate where along the X the current animation frame is in the texture:

```
m_animationData.x = (m_animationData.width * m_currentFrame);
```

So consider if I have a 128x32 sprite sheet, and the size of the sprite is 32x32, that makes it have 4 frames of animation. Each frame would then have an X equivalent of

frame 0: 0
frame 1: 32
frame 2: 64
frame 3: 96

All that is missing is how to tell the shader to render just that portion of the texture.

Comment: "*since that would become extremely costly*" Why do you figure that?

Comment: Recreating a vbo every time a sprite updates. Sounds like a lot of processing cost. Consider I have 100+ sprites animating..

Comment: Modifying the VBO contents is not recreating the vbo

Comment: What do I do to avoid that?

Comment: you cannot really get around that I think, you'll have to tell the gpu every time you change your selections of vertices on a texture, however this is not very resource intensive, and it is far far slower uploading a new texture everytime

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. Now to ponder whether I should stick with one vbo that is shared or one per sprite.